# MKAnnotationView for userLocation pin iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mapkit, mkmapview

I have an application that uses MKMapView and at some point in the app I need to remove all the current pins in the map using

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]
```

And then I want to show again the current user location

```
mapView.showUserLocation = YES
```

But I can only make it reappear as a regular pin, because the userLocation view class its not public so I cant return views of that type. Here is my code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

MKPinAnnotationView* annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

if (!annView) {
   MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
  annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
  annView.canShowCallout = YES;
  annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[DraggableAnnotationAM class]] ) annView.draggable =YES;
  return annView;

}
else {
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[DraggableAnnotationAM class]] ) annView.draggable =     YES;
  annView.annotation = annotation;
  return annView;
 }
```

Also I have found through reflection that

```
MKUserLocationView
```

is the class that is used to display the current location, but because its not public its not safe to use and my app keeps crashing and Im sure theres a easier way.

Is it possible to do what I want, or should I just never remove the user location annotation of the mapView?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it with an NSMutableArray. Hope this helps you solving your problem!

```
 NSMutableArray *annotation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (id <MKAnnotation> annot_ in [mapView annotations])
 {
     if ( [annot_ isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] ) {
     }
     else {
         [annotation addObject:annot_];
     }
 }

 [mapView removeAnnotations:annotation];   
 [annotation release];   
 annotation = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show a blue dot for the user's location in stead of a regular pin, return nil in this mapView delegate function. Alternatively return your own MKAnnotationView (subclass) object:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil // or return a custom MKAnnotationView
        } else { // etc.
```